# I'm trying to install Spicetify and I'm stuck at config.ini step

Tags: software-installation, configuration

I'm following the instruction, but I'm stuck at config.ini step.

https://spicetify.app/docs/advanced-usage/installation/

I was able to find the folder

> /var/lib/flatpak/app/com.spotify.Client/x86_64/stable/active/files/extra/share/spotify/

How can I access this config.ini for me to change the spotify_path? [image: config.ini]

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop, Spotify installed via Flatpak

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about the documentation quality for a 3rd party package provider. Maybe you should ask the Spicetify people directly where their config file is located?

Comment: Try using the apt version of spotify.

Answer (score 0):

**prefs_path:**

```
/home/username/.var/app/com.spotify.Client/config/spotify/prefs
```

**spotify_path:**

```
/home/username/.local/share/flatpak/app/com.spotify.Client/x86_64/stable/active/files/extra/share/spotify/
```

i am using POP OS, i think it should be the same.

**Just change the username to yours.**
if the repo does not exist than open spotify first that should create it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I too am using Ubuntu 22.04 and my spicetify config file is at `~/.config/spicetify/config-xpui.ini`. I found this by prompting the terminal with `spicetify config-dir`, and it opened my config directory of spicetify.

To change the spotify path, change the value of

```
spotify_path            = <your-file-path>
```

to your spotify path.

[image]

---

Hope this works for you and good luck.